# When minimax theorem does not hold: counterexample of absence of convexity

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

I know that the conditions to have that

$\min_{y\in Y} \max_{x\in X} f(x,y)=\max_{x\in X} \min_{y\in Y} f(x,y)$

are that $X,Y$ are compact and convex subsets of the product of reals and that $f$ is continuous and quasi-concave on $y$ and quasi-convex on $x$. I am trying to find particular cases in which I violate one of the conditions and get an inequality.

In particular, I am struggling to find $X$ or $Y$ not convex such that for $f: X\times Y \rightarrow R$, continuous, quasi-concave on $y$ and quasi-convex on $x$,

$\min_{y\in Y} \max_{x\in X} f(x,y)\neq \max_{x\in X} \min_{y\in Y} f(x,y)$.

I think my issue is probably related to a misunderstanding of the theorem (I can prove it but cannot check its conclusion).

Comment: If you don 't put any conditions on $f$ and $g$ then $f(x,y)=1$ for $x=y$ and $0$ for $x \neq y$ is a counter-example.

Comment: I will add them

Comment: And what are you meaning by $g$?

Comment: Sorry, just ignore the $g$ in my comment.

Comment: It helps if we are looking for a non-continuous, no q-convex on $x$ function

Comment: I can define $X=Y=[0,1] \cap [2,3]$ and define $f$ in each square. It would still be continuous

Comment: If you mean $[0,1]\times [2,3]$ then $f$ is just the zero function.

Comment: No, $([0,1]\cap [2,3]) \times ([0,1]\cap [2,3]) $

Comment: $[0,1]\cap [2,3]$ is the empty set.

Comment: Sorry, $([0,1]\cup[2,3])\times([0,1]\cup[2,3])$

Comment: This set includes $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ so $f$ is not continuous on it.

Comment: I considered defining a $g$ s.t. in every square of the domain is constant. No the same $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a set $X$ with just two points. On $X\times X$ define $f(x,y)=1$ if $x=y$ and $0$ otherwise. This is example where min and max cannot be switched but $f$ is continuous.